# Отображение названия файла в input File

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

На сайте есть динамические поля для загрузки файлов. А также используется bootstrap 4.3.1.

При выборе файла, в поле отображается его название.

Но когда добавить новое динамическое поле и загрузить файл, то поле с названием - пустое, но файл там есть.

Как можно сделать, чтобы название и там отображалося???

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 99;
  var addButton = $('.add_button');
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
  var $x = 1;

  $(addButton).click(function() {
    if ($x < maxField) {
      var fieldHTML = '<div id="field" class="row ui-state-default align-items-center"><div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center;"><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></div><div class="col-md-10"><div class="row align-items-center"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="custom-file"><input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="service-img" name="service_img[]"><label class="custom-file-label" for="service-img">Выбрать</label></div></div></div></div><div class="col-md-1 remove_button"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">-</a></div></div>';
      $x++;
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('#field').remove();
    $x--;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kbu.com.ua/resource/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kbu.com.ua/resource/js/docs.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kbu.com.ua/resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="field_wrapper field_wrapper admin-sortable" id="sortable">
  <div id="field" class="row ui-state-default align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center;"><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="custom-file"><input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="service-img-'.$Row['id'].'" name="service_img[]"><label class="custom-file-label" for="service-img-'.$Row['id'].'">Выбрать</label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 remove_button"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">-</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button_wrapper add_button" title="Добавить услугу">+ Добавить услугу</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Должно помочь (не забудьте итерировать id динамических инпутов и forы их лейблов):

```
$('body').on('change', '.custom-file-input', function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0].name;
  $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(file);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 99;
  var addButton = $('.add_button');
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
  var $x = 1;

  $(addButton).click(function() {
    if ($x < maxField) {
      var fieldHTML = '<div id="field" class="row ui-state-default align-items-center"><div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center;"><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></div><div class="col-md-10"><div class="row align-items-center"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="custom-file"><input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="service-img-1" name="service_img[]"><label class="custom-file-label" for="service-img-1">Выбрать</label></div></div></div></div><div class="col-md-1 remove_button"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">-</a></div></div>';
      $x++;
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('#field').remove();
    $x--;
  });
  
  $('body').on('change', '.custom-file-input', function (e) { // <---
    var file = e.target.files[0].name;                        // <---
    $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(file);            // <---
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kbu.com.ua/resource/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kbu.com.ua/resource/js/docs.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kbu.com.ua/resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="field_wrapper field_wrapper admin-sortable" id="sortable">
  <div id="field" class="row ui-state-default align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center;"><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="custom-file"><input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="service-img-0" name="service_img[]"><label class="custom-file-label" for="service-img-0">Выбрать</label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 remove_button"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">-</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button_wrapper add_button" title="Добавить услугу">+ Добавить услугу</a>
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Попробую